# failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have two classes having a one to many relationship:  `OpinionPoll` (one) and `PollResult` (many).

When I execute the criteria query below the following error is raised:
**Failed to lazilyinitialize a collection of role: com.bonrix.gcm.demo.model.OpinionPoll.pollResults, could not initialize proxy - no Session.**

I just want to query only the parent (OpinionPoll class) records. But i got the above error and due to my requirement I have to use FetchType=Lazy.

Here is the mapping of my two classes:

```
Opinionpoll mapping:

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="opinionPoll",fetch=FetchType. LAZY)
private List<PollResult> pollResults = new ArrayList<PollResult>() ;


PollResult mapping:

@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL },fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "poll_id")           
private OpinionPoll opinionPoll;


Query:

Criteria criteria = 
  session.createCriteria(OpinionPoll.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("clientName", username))
    .addOrder(Order.desc("pollId"))
    .setMaxResults(maxpoll)
    .setFirstResult(offset);
opinionPolls = criteria.list();
```

Comment: Check why your session have been closed.

Comment: Where is the `NHibernate Session` being managed ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to something like

```
40 : using(var session = factory.OpenSession())
41 : {
42 :        // load object in your case `OpinionPoll`
43 : }

// access collection on object , in your case `PollResult`

44 : var firstResult =     OpinionPoll.PollResults.First()
```

you need to access `PollResults` before the session is closed (before line 43), where the session will lazily load the poll results on access.